# How to get all "title" values from dictionary of array in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

## Swift 5

I want to get **array** of all values from "**title**" key

```
// Create variable
var arrSportsList:[[String:String]] = []

    // viewDidLoad code
    arrSportsList = [
        ["title":"Cricket"],
        ["title":"Soccer"],
        ["title":"American Football"],
        ["title":"Ice Hockey"],
        ["title":"Tennis"],
        ["title":"Baseball"],
        ["title":"Basketball"],
        ]
```

I want to use this title in picker view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`compactMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap) method to get the title value from all dictionaries. If any dictionary doesn't contain title key it will be ignored

```
var arrSportsList:[[String:String]] = []

// viewDidLoad code
arrSportsList = [
    ["title1":"anothergame"],
    ["title":"Cricket"],
    ["title":"Soccer"],
    ["title":"American Football"],
    ["title":"Ice Hockey"],
    ["title":"Tennis"],
    ["title":"Baseball"],
    ["title":"Basketball"],
    ]


let titleArr = arrSportsList.compactMap { $0["title"] }
print(titleArr)//Cricket,Soccer,American Football,Ice Hockey,Tennis,Baseball,Basketball
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`compactMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap):

```
let titleArr = arrSportsList.compactMap { $0["title"] }
```

It transforms each dictionary to the value associated with the key `title`, and removes the dictionaries which don't have a `title` key.

I also suggest you to create a class/struct to store these sports, instead of dictionaries:

```
struct Sport {
    let title: String
    // other properties
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way

```
 let titleArr = arrSportsList.compactMap { $0["title"] }
```

Or you can loop through the dictionary array and can get the titles Like

```
 let titleArr = Array<String>();
    for dict in arrSportsList {
        if let title = dict["title"] {
             titleArr.append(title);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of understanding more, you can use

```
// Create variable

var arrSportsList:[[String:String]] = []

// viewDidLoad code
arrSportsList = [
    ["title":"Cricket"],
    ["title":"Soccer"],
    ["title":"American Football"],
    ["title":"Ice Hockey"],
    ["title":"Tennis"],
    ["title":"Baseball"],
    ["title":"Basketball"],
    ]

var titleArray: [String]
for (key, value) in arrSportsList {
    print (key) // "title"
    print (value) //Cricket, Soccer, American Football, Ice Hockey, Tennis, Baseball, Basketball
    titleArray.append(value)
}
print (titleArray) //Cricket, Soccer, American Football, Ice Hockey, Tennis, Baseball, Basketball
```